# Search engine for DROPDOWN and HREF

Tags: javascript, html

Based on this search engine: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_filters_anything

This is my "project": http://m3u8.eshost.com.ar/demo/index.html

There are 3 cards: Number 1 and 2 contain a drop down. Number 3 a simple HREF.

There is nothing defined in the script to find the number 3, so it is always visible.

I would like to know what I have to modify in the script to find the TITLE for the number 3 (as I have done with 1 and 2)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
$(".numbers > .dropdown").filter(function() {
  $(this).toggle($(this).find("a").attr("title").toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
});
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$(".numbers > .dropdown").filter` will only filter `dropdown` elements that are children of `.numbers` elements. You need to also filter an element without a dropdown (e.g. `$(".numbers").filter`)

Comment: Please post a minimal working example in your question using the snippet option.